# screen is white, react native newbie

Tags: react-native

```
const Hello = () => {
  const txt=useSelector(state => state.reducer.number);
  const dispatch=useDispatch();
  <>
   <View>
  <Button title="+" onPress={dispatch(numIncrement())} />
  <Text>{txt}</Text>
 
</View>
</>

}

const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <Hello/>

    </Provider>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I wrapped hello in provider and i am using redux here which is simply increase the number every time i will tap the button.

Comment: It seems like you forgot to `return` your JSX. Add a `return` statement to your `Hello` component.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this

```xml
const Hello = () => {
  const txt=useSelector(state => state.reducer.number);
  const dispatch=useDispatch();
  
  return ( 
   <>
   <View>
    <Button title="+" onPress={dispatch(numIncrement())} />
    <Text>{txt}</Text>
   </View>
  </> 
  )
}
```